# PHP / jquery mail in local network

Tags: php, jquery, email, intranet

Normally I post my questions with my code, but this time, I have a question for you guys that I don't know were to start.

On my company I have made a web application in the local network. So I have a PC acting like a server with apache and then all other machines can access the site via the hostname of the server machine.

We use Microsoft Lotus Notes and Outlook to manage the mails in the company.

Is it possible to send mails via PHP or jquery on a local network? Can I send the emails via the users mail client? On visual basic I used to do this, the mail client of the user would send the email without the user notice at all.

The localhost doesn't work as as a SMTP server, right?

Thank you for your answer.

**EDIT**

I found a solution:

[hMailSever](http://www.hmailserver.com/)

Comment: Can you not just set up the SMTP address and go from there?

Comment: I have done that. But no mail was received.

Comment: It'll need t be sent via the internet. I dont know how you set up an internal one

Comment: That's my problem also. I know that is possible to configure a SMTP server via IIS on the localhost. But I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to send mail from the user, but it wouldn't be via the user's mail client. Something like this

```
mail('recipient@otherDomain.com','subject','message','From: sender@yourDomain.com');
```

Comment: But since my application is not connected to the Internet, will the mail be sent? Does apache as mail server?